# translate t-sql in linq

Tags: linq

How can I write the below t-sql in Linq?

```
select (select COUNT(col1) FROM t2 WHERE col2 = t1.col2 and col1 = t1.col1) as total,

 t1.col1,t1.col2...................

from t1
```

Comment: Sorry. what do you mean?

Comment: He means that SO is an aid for developers not a solution. Try it yourself. If you get it wrong, post what you're trying to do and i'm sure enough guys here would be more than happy to help.

Comment: I'm not sure how to start with it. I'm new to linq. I know some basics about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var res = from t1 in context.t1s
    select new
    {
        total = context.t2s.Where(t2=> t2.col1 == t1.col1 && t2.col2 == t1.col2).Count(),
        t1.col1,
        t1.col2,
    };
```

**Edit:**
And if you have your FK-relations set up correctly in the database and your DBML you can use the simpler version below

```
var res = from t1 in context.t1s
    select new
    {
        total = t1.t2s.Count(),
        t1.col1,
        t1.col2,
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using LinqPad. It is great for translating between SQL and LINQ queries.

http://www.linqpad.net/